# XMLHttpRequest main progress bar

Tags: xmlhttprequest, program-entry-point, progress

I have created a progress bar to download images. All work fine just would like to show the download status of all files rather than individual.

```
var xhrList = [];
var link = [];

$('img').each(function() {
    link.push($(this).attr("src"));
});
var width = $('.logo img').width();
$('#logo').css({'width': 0, 'overflow': 'hidden'});     
for (var i=0; i< link.length; i++){
    xhrList[i] = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhrList[i].open('GET', link[i], true);
    xhrList[i].responseType = "blob";
    console.log(xhrList[i]);
    xhrList[i].onprogress = function(e) {
        if (e.lengthComputable) {
            ProgressPerc = parseInt((e.loaded / e.total) * 100);
            $('#logo').stop().animate({'width': ProgressPerc + '%'},200);}
    };
    xhrList[i].send();
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ag8L9zmk/7/